# Issue with Relationships in Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, foreign-keys, primary-key, relationship

I am currently working within Access 2013. I have a simple task that has been really driving me crazy these past few days, as I thought my relationships where correct. But when adding more data into the database I saw that there was a major problem.

[image]

Within the database everything is working fine between tblPersonal Information and tblPosition Applied for. The problem that I am running into is trying to successfully create the one to many relationship between tblPosition Applied for and tblOffer

I am trying to make it so that:

```
one person can apply to many positions (one to many) 
one position that each person applies for can have one contingent offer (one to many) "the root of the problem that I am having"
```

Is their a field that I need to add, or create another table holding just the Personal ID to link tblPosition Applied for and tblOffer? I am really lost on this any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now there are no fields that are related except `Personal_ID` in the offers and applied tables.  Essentially, there would be no way to distinguish if Person A applied for Job 1 and Job 2, and received an offer for Job 2.

In your `tbl_Offer`, there should be a `Position_ID` that relates to the Position.  Also, assuming that the offer is only valid for one person, there is no need for `tbl_Offer` to contain a `Personal_ID` field, as it would be related through the `tblPosition_Applied_For`.

Comment: But how would I relate tbl_Offer to tblPosition_Applied_for if i remove Personal_ID from tbl_Offer? What field within tblPosition_Applied_for should be related to tbl_Offer to create a (one to many)?

Comment: You should create a `Position_ID` field in the `tbl_Offer` table

Comment: Thank you, but I am running into another problem this worked great if you are working within the table but not a form. Within my form I have two subforms tblPosition Applied for Subform and tblOffer Subform. How do I link tblOffer Subform to tblPersonal Information, as Access is only display tblPersonal Information as the parent form and not tblPosition Applied for.

Comment: I would make the offer a subform of positions applied, and positions applied a subform of personal info.

Comment: I am able to successfully link Position Applied for Subform to Personal Information, but I am having trouble linking tblOffer to tblPosition Applied for. What should be my Master and Child fields for tblOffer?

Comment: The Master and Child fields are the fields which hold the relationship.  Your Master should be ID and your Child should be Position_ID.

Answer (score 1):

If a `Position_applied_For` can have one-to-many offers, then you need to create a related field in `tbl_Offer`, just as you did for the one-to-many relationship between `tbl_Personal_Information` and `tblPosition_Applied_For`.  Change `tbl_Offer.Personal_ID` to `tbl_Offer.Position_Applied_For` and relate it back to `tblPosition_Applied_For.ID`.